# Barcode font removes space between characters

Tags: reporting-services, fonts, barcode, barcode-scanner, reportbuilder3.0

I'm using Report Builder 3.0 and it gives me a font to make barcodes with. It's called `Code39QuarterInch`. However, the problem is that when my string has a space in between some of the characters, the barcode font removes it.

For example, it takes `LN 300` and turns it into a barcode, but this barcode scans like `LN300`. Does anyone know of another font I can use to fix this? Or is there maybe a workaround?

Comment: You could use "=" or "_" instead of whitespace.

Comment: @OscarMartinez The barcode needs to return `LN 300` precisely. I can't have a different character in there because this value will be used as input in something else.

Comment: You can also use the fonts placed in the `Fonts with Barcode Symbol in Space Character` folder.

Comment: @OscarMartinez is that a folder that comes with the installation of Report Builder 3.0?

Comment: It comes in the Code 39 Barcode Fonts, you can find it [here](http://www.idautomation.com/barcode-fonts/code-39/download.html)

Comment: @OscarMartinez ah, the catch here is that I can't really download and install anything. I am only a lowly peon at my company and must work with whatever they give me, which is the Report Builder 3.0 program.

Comment: @OscarMartinez nevermind, the underscore worked. Idk why it didn't before, but I'm all set now. Thanks